# Ground state of $\rm Co^{2+}$ in ${\rm CoO}$ (Cobalt oxide)

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, strong-correlated

According to this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.116.281), $\rm Co^{2+}$ ion in ${\rm CoO}$ has a ground state of $t_{2g}^5e_g^2$ with a mixture of $t_{2g}^4e_g^3$. The latter belongs to the first excited state of 4P. This makes me confused. How could the excited state be the ground state at the same time?

Comment: Why is the sum of coefficients not 1?
The sum of squared coefficients needs to be 1: $0.97^2+0.25^2=1$

Comment: Thanks and that is a stupid question and I just deleted it.